# AdonisJS migration to postgresql /kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, adonisjs-ace, lucid

hello i am new in kubernetes and i test the deployment of a small app in adonis js with db postgresql , so i want to know how to make a migration of the model present in adonis js automatically after the deployment of the pods and the services
Thank you.

Comment: To avoid misunderstanding, could you please describe what exactly you would like to achieve? Do you need to migrate your application to be deployed in Kubernetes? How exactly is your cluster configured - version, bare metal/cloud?

Comment: no I would like to migrate the schema of the model that I have in project to  postgres db  to create tables on postgresql, in adonis we use the command node ace make:migration and all this after deploying my pods